# What is the syntax of ImageResize()

Tags: image, syntax, dm-script

I have data that change in size and want to display them in the same window.  The command

```
void ImageResize( BasicImage im, Number num_dim, Number... )
```

seems like a potential fit, but the syntax is not clear at all.
Let's say I have 512x5 data set and now it needs to be 367x5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `, Number...)` indicates that this command takes a different number of parameters, all of them interpreted as `number` parameters. Commands which do this, usually use one of their other parameters to specify how many such parameters follow. 
A typical example for this is also the `SliceN` command.

In this particular case, the command not only allows you to change the size of the dimensions in the image, but also the number of dimensions. It is a very useful command to f.e. change a 2D image into a 3D stack or the like.

> **The command `ImageResize( BasicImage im, Number num_dim, Number... )` does several things:**
>
> - It replaces `im` in-place, so the meta-data, display and window remains the same
> - It *adjusts the dimension calibration* when the dimension size is changed. Here, the assumption is, that the field-of-view before and
>     after the resize is the same. (The command can be used to easily scale
>     images as shown in the example below.)
> - All values of the image `im` are set to zero. ( If you need to keep the values, you need to act on an image clone!)

---

### Example 1: Resizing image with bilinar interpolation

```
image before := GetFrontImage()
number sx, sy
before.GetSize(sx,sy)
number factor = 1.3
image after := before.ImageClone()  
after.ImageResize( 2, factor*sx, factor*sy )    // Adjusts the empty container with meta-data 
after = warp(before, icol/factor, irow/factor ) // interpolate data
after.ShowImage()
```

## Example 2: Extend 2D image into 3D stack

```
number sx = 100
number sy = 100
image img := RealImage("2D",4,sx,sy)
img = iradius* Random()
img.ShowImage()
OKDialog("Now into a stack...")
number sz = 10
img.ImageResize(3,sx,sy,sz) // All values are zero now!
img = iradius * Random()
```

Comment: A warning when using 'ImageResize()'. If used on a line plot display and there are more than 1 graphs in the plot, the plot can turn white and show diagonal black lines. It seems to happen randomly.  Using the key combo "control D" on that plot will create a hard exit for GMS.  I am using GMS 3.3.0 build 2016.

Comment: This seems to be a bug related to changing an image's display type to "LinePlot" *before* the image is displayed using `ShowImage()` or the like. You can avoid this by avoiding to call the command `SetDisplayType()` on images not yet having a display.